# Protractor Visual Studio Code Debug Error Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 sec

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, protractor

Protractor Visual Studio Code Debug Error Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 sec - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:36406).

Below is my launch.json file configuration

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {            
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via npm",            
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script", "regression_sat",
                "--inspect=5858"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

and below is the package.json file with scripts tag

```
"scripts": {
    "webdriver-start": "npm_webdriver.bat",
    "protractor": "protractor_batch.bat"
    "regression_sat": "node_modules/.bin/protractor.cmd ./config/protractor.chrome.conf.js --suite suite_sat --params.env sat"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason causing this error is because the browser window that was launched by Visual Studio was still running when the debug session terminated. This prevents the next debug session from starting up successfully.

Close the browser window itself instead of the tab running your application once you are done with the debug session. This will ensure that the next debug session can start a new instance of the browser for debugging.